# Send GCM push notification via notification_key (HTTP)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notification to multiple user's devices via HTTP.

As [docs](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html#params) says:

> A request must include a recipient—this can be either a registration ID, an array of registration IDs, or a notification_key. Required.
>
> A 3rd-party server can use notification_key as the target for a message instead of an individual registration ID (or array of registration IDs).

Simplified code:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("project_id", PROJECT_ID);
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key="+AUTH_KEY);

JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
JSONArray ids = new JSONArray();
ids.add(NOTIF_KEY);
body.put("notification_key", ids);

conn.setDoOutput(true);
BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())));
body.writeJSONString(wr);

wr.flush();
wr.close();

int respCode = conn.getResponseCode();
```

As a result I have 400 (Bad request) response code and "Missing "registration_ids" field" error message.

I am tried to include blank registration_id parameter and also put my NOTIF_ID in it, nothing changes.

The body of my request is simple as IE's blankpage

```
{"notification_key":["APA91bGm6LpfKo0_iPWIyUAtvYj7zMmdlMRN802wfsUeq8XaCThRbIcVXMIzwhL4MXr61522UppK--Qory2Zqa5e7o9thZo2tQYOYXBX8fP9sI3WpwSPSK0"]}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of notification_key, user registration_ids. Also you need to add data JsonObject block for sending data.

See the below example.

```
{ "collapse_key": "score_update",
  "time_to_live": 108,
  "delay_while_idle": true,
  "data": {
    "score": "4x8",
    "time": "15:16.2342"
  },
  "registration_ids":["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not an correct answer, because my main problem is sending via **notification_key**